# Best way to create Rails route for both resource (singular) AND resources (plural)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a `profile` model in my application.  I want to allow a user to view their own profile via `/profile`, so I created this route:

```
resource :profile, :only => :show
```

I also want the user to be able to view other users' profiles via `/profiles/joeblow`, so I created this route:

```
resources :profiles, :only => :show
```

The problem is, in the second case, there is an `:id` parameter that I want to use to find the profile.  In the first case, I just want to use the logged in user's profile.

This is what I'm using to find the right profile, but I'm wondering if there's a more appropriate way I could be doing this.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_profile!
  before_filter :find_profile

  def show
  end

  private

    def find_profile
      @profile = params[:id] ? Profile.find_by_name(params[:id]) : current_profile
    end
 end
```

**Edit**: One of the problems with this method is my routes.  It's not possible for me to call `profile_path` without passing a profile/ID parameter, meaning anytime I have to use the string '/profile' whenever I need to link there.

```
$ rake routes | grep profile
  profile GET    /profiles/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}
          GET    /profile(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routes:

```
resource :profile, :only => :show, :as => :current_profile, :type => :current_profile
resources :profiles, :only => :show
```

Then your `ProfilesController`

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_profile!
  before_filter :find_profile

  def show
  end

  private

  def find_profile
    @profile = params[:type] ? Profile.find(params[:id]) : current_profile
  end
end
```

Your `Profile` model

```
class Profile < AR::Base
  def to_param
    name
  end
end
```

Views:

```
<%= link_to "Your profile", current_profile_path %>
<%= link_to "#{@profile.name}'s profile", @profile %>
# or 
<%= link_to "#{@profile.name}'s profile", profile_path( @profile ) %>
```

Also: if Profile is a model, you

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like that makes the URL `/current_profile` instead of `/profile`, unless I'm missing something.  But I guess that's the only way of solving this?